# Why does removing a "metapackage" not remove the dependencies which it installed?

Tags: deb, metapackages

If I attempt to uninstall a metapackage, `apt` does not actually remove the metapackage's dependencies, only the "wrapper" itself. Even when running `apt autoremove`, these subpackages are not listed. I find it confusing that `autoremove` removes dependencies for most normal packages, but not many metapackages. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta-packages are not magic in any regard: the concept "of meta-package" is not part of the APT system - a meta-package is simply a package which doesn't have actual content, just dependencies. So removing them has the same effect as removing a package with actual content that also depends on some other stuff, like a web server application module will require a web server, but when you remove it - the web server should still stay installed.

That being said, APT keeps track of which packages were automatically installed because another package requested them (like a meta-package requesting "actual" packages, or a web server application module requiring a web server), and once you remove the requiring package APT will suggest you run `apt autoremove` to get rid of such automatically installed packages.

The main problem with "meta-packages" as they are used in the Ubuntu operating system is that they depend on a lot of packages, essentially installing a huge selection of software with a single install. When installing so many packages, especially such that are very closely tied together - you can get a lot of cross-dependencies: the meta package requires packages `A`, `B` and `C` for you, but `A` also depends on `B` and `B` (maybe surprisingly) also depends on `A`. So if you remove the meta-package, only `C` will get removed.

As a concrete example, lets consider the LXDE meta-package `lubuntu-desktop`:

- [`lubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lubuntu-desktop) requires [`lxqt-core`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lxqt-core)
- [`lxqt-core`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lxqt-core) requires [`lxqt-panel`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lxqt-panel)
- [`lxqt-panel`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lxqt-panel) depends on [`lxqt-core`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/lxqt-core). Actually, this dependency is not `Requires`, but `Recommends` - but that should be enough for apt to decide not to automatically remove either package.

The following answers have more details:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447957/4323
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265186/4323

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I guess I should have stated my question better. A lot of times it seems that `apt autoremove` does not show any of the metapackage's dependencies, while it would if a "normal" package was uninstalled. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @tech4him: I edited my answer to address your edit

Comment: Thanks! It has happened for most alternative desktop environments I've tried to install on a regular (GNOME) base system (`xubuntu-desktop`, `kubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop`, etc). To uninstall, I've always had to go back to the Apt log.

Comment: @tech4him - after a bit more research, I have a better answer for you.

Comment: That example would also explain why a package with a cyclic dependency, but installed directly (not via metapackage), would still autoremove. When it is below another "layer", those asumptions do not work as well. I'm assuming cyclic dependencies are less common in non-"core" packages such as desktops (but still possible).

Comment: I think "a meta-package is simply a package which doesn't have actual content, just dependencies" could be modified to "a meta-package is simply a *package* which lists which packages and their dependencies will be installed if the meta-package is installed". In other words, the meta-package is a *list* of "primary" packages, not their dependencies.

Comment: You are correct in concept, but technically the dependencies in a meta-package are no different than the dependencies if a standard package, and APT treats them the same - which is the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

**ALL packages installed by the Ubuntu's *ubiquity* installer** are apt-marked 'Manual' (instead of 'Auto), making all those packages ineligible for autoremoval.

You can still remove them, of course, you just cannot *autoremove* them.

The Ubuntu Server, Minimal Image, and Cloud Image installers are not based on ubiquity, and their packages *are* eligible for autoremoval.

**If you are not familiar with *apt-marking***, it's simply how apt keeps track of which dependencies were specified by the admin (*'Manual'*), and which were pulled in as dependencies (*'Auto'*). See `man apt-mark` for more information about it.

**The reason for the non-standard Ubiquity behavior** is to protect you: Folks modify their desktop systems in all kinds of ways, including ways that require removal of the metapackage. Most users don't usually intend to remove their entire desktop, doing so unexpected can be a rather Significant Emotional Event, so the Ubuntu developers made the change to protect users from their own (unintended) folly. After all, Ubuntu is intended for new and unskilled users, too.

Folks who want to prune their packages to just what they actually use (we all have tried that at one time or another) will find it much easier to start from the [Minimal Image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and build up rather than fight the apt-marking to cut down.

Comment: That's a very good point, although I was mostly asking about a secondary metapackage install after the system was already installed. Does this answer address this at all, or is it only regarding initial install? It's helpful either way -- I'd just like to clarify.

Comment: After the installed system is running, then the Ubiquity change no longer applies, of course. All apt actions will be normal: *Newly-installed* dependencies will be apt-marked 'auto', and will be eligible for auto-removal.