# Libreoffice folder still in lib after uninstall

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, libreoffice, 21.04

I uninstalled LibreOffice using:

```
sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice
```

on Ubuntu 21.04, but when I look at my `lib` folder, there is still a folder `libreoffice` with binaries, libraries, etc. When I try to remove `libreoffice` again using `apt`, it claims that LibreOffice is not installed.

Is `apt` lying to me? Also, how can I completely remove LibreOffice?

Comment: you need to use `lbreoffice*` instead. Without the asterisk it merely removes the (empty) meta-package `libreoffice`, nothing that was installed because of it.

Comment: @ChaganAuto Thank you, that solved the issue (and explains why the folder was still there).

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does removing a “metapackage” not remove the dependencies which it installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111491/why-does-removing-a-metapackage-not-remove-the-dependencies-which-it-installed)